# Batch - move files into alphabetical forders including unicode or 'strange' characters

Tags: batch-processing

I have some files and I want to move them inside alphabetical folder NOT previously created. With batch I want generate folders. Theses files must be moved inside these folders following files's first letter

I have a multi language file list inside my directory like this:

```
中文
alfa
35h
Ĕuid
لعربية
សេវិនខ្មែរ
```

I try this command to move files into alphabetic folders using first folder letter for ordering

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set first=%%i
  set first=!first:~0,1!
  md !first! 2>nul
  if not "!first!" == "%%i" move "%%i" "!first!\%%i" 
)
```

Nothing happens.

 This part

```
for /d %%i in (*) do (
```

create folders and move folders and not files but I want move files inside generated folders (I don't want create folders previously)

Comment: You say that you have a "file list", but you're using `for /d`, which only works with directories, not files. Are these actually files or directories?

Comment: Also, what's the name of the 4th one in your list? Question marks aren't valid filename characters in Windows. Did you really somehow get a file/folder with question marks in its name, or is that a copy/paste or a SO display error or something?

Comment: @Elezar: I'm sure it's not a question mark. It's the ? that is displayed when a Unicode character can't be represented using the current font or code page. It can't be a question mark (ASCII 0x3F/decimal 63) because that's not an allowable character for a file/folder name, as you say.

Comment: Peter: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900%28v=ws.10%29.aspx (or type `for /?` at a command prompt), where you'll see that Elezar is correct; `/d` means *directories only*, which means it cannot affect files. When in doubt, start with the documentation. And for future reference, *Nothing happens. Any help?* is a horrific problem description and question. *No files get copied* would even be better than *Nothing happens*, and *Any help?* can be answered with *Yes, we can help* with no other information and be complete.

Comment: @Elezar I have some files and I want to move them inside alphabetical folder NOT previously created. With batch I want generate folders. These files must be moved inside these folders following files's first letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently using `for /d` which works on directories, not files. Since you have files, you need your for loop to work on them. If you just remove the `/d`, it will do so. However, note that this means it will also move the batch file itself. If you don't want that, then you'll need to put in logic to exclude it. Something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in (*) do (
  set first=%%i
  if not "!first!" == "%0" (
    set first=!first:~0,1!
    md !first! 2>nul
    if not "!first!" == "%%i" move "%%i" "!first!\%%i" 
  )
)
```

**EDIT FOR ! SUPPORT**

If the filename contains an exclamation mark, it won't work, because when delayed expansion is enabled, it sees that as part of a variable delimiter. The way to get around it is to assign the filename to a variable **before** you enable delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%i in (*) do (
  set name=%%i
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  if not "!name!" == "%0" (
    set first=!name:~0,1!
    md !first! 2>nul
    if not "!first!" == "!name!" move "!name!" "!first!\!name!" 
  )
)
```

Comment: your command works almost perfectly but for characters like `!` batch don't work. Why?

Comment: I've edited my answer with info on how to work with ! in filenames when delayed expansion is enabled.